# React + typescript: InferProps for propTypes.elementType throws error: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use proptypes InferProps together with propTypes.elementType:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import propTypes, { InferProps }from 'prop-types'

const MyComponentPropTypes = {
    component: propTypes.elementType,
}

const MyComponent = ({
    component: Component
}: InferProps<typeof MyComponentPropTypes>) => {
    return (
        <Component />
    )
}
```

But I get:

> Error:(12, 4) TS2604: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.

I tried all propType values from documentation and the only one that seems to work is `propTypes.any`

Switching from `InferProps<typeof MyComponentPropTypes>` to `{ component: React.ComponentType }` also works fine, but I would like to get `InferProps` working. How do I do that?

Comment: Huh, I don't think I've ever seen `prop-types` used with TypeScript since TS gives you all the type safety you need. Maybe I'm missing something: why use them both?

Comment: It is correct. You dont need prop types with typescript.

Comment: Because TypeScript doesn't do runtime checks. propTypes warn you whenever wrong types get actually passed into the component - for example when data served by backend does not match the expected shape.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after struggling for few hours I found the solution, you have to add to your propType isRequired.

So the solution for you is to change

`component: propTypes.elementType`

to

`component: propTypes.elementType.isRequired`

Why you have to add `.isRequired`? Because `null` or `undefined` can not be instantiated or do any call. Even the error kind tells you that "does not have any construct or call signatures.". You can see if you hover without adding `.isRequired` that compiler see as it can have `null` or `undefined` values which is correct.